# exponent mod $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, definition

What does the term "exponent mod $n$" refer to? I guessed that this refers to the multiplicative order mod n, but it doesn't look like this is the case in what I'm reading right now.

Comment: What are you reading right now?

Comment: Could you provide the whole sentence in which that phrase is used?

Comment: It could just mean $x^k\pmod n$. But, as everybody noted, it really depends on the context, and you have given none.

Comment: The *exponent* $e$ of a group $G$ is the least positive number such that $g^e=1$ for each $g\in G$, for example. In this case, maybe we're thinking about the group $\left(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\right)^\times$.

Comment: I should have added the what context the term was used in. I was going to post the article, but it isn't something you can find for free, so I wasn't sure whether I was allowed to post it or not. The general subject was related to the period of the Fibonacci sequence mod $n$.

Answer (score 1):

I know this from decoding RSA algorithms where it means

$$\text{number}^{\text {exponent}}\; \text {mod} \;N$$